# How can i disable Left Option Key

Tags: keyboard

My kebyboard seems to stuck. The option key is always engaged and i get special characters each time I type. I need to disable the Left Option key. Please Help me.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with your hardware. You need to physically fix your hardware. Any attempts to override the option key signal is going to start mucking up the signal gate. You can't just fix the issue from the software side of things - that won't change the fact that the keyboard hardware is transmitting the signal that the option key is being pressed.

If you need it disabled, then physically disable it. Grab a screwdriver.

Comment: My key is not physically stuck. The option key engages time to time, typing is hard as it enables special characters. I have assigned the option key to caps lock and vice versa but still caps lock is engaged to make my typing a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said option key, I assumed you are using a Mac. In that case I would suggest you use keyboard remapping tool such as [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to remap the bothersome key to something less annoying (or disable it all together if possible)

As skub mentioned, fixing the hardware would be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tis true, skub is correct. If you pop out a Mac key, it's (usually) easy to pop it right back into place. Once you pop it out, you will see a little rubber bubble piece. If you'd like to disable the key, you could probably get away with just removing that little rubber piece - they pop right off. Really though, once the key is off, just clean the area out with a piece of cloth dabbed in a bit of rubbing alcohol (while the power is off). You'll probably have no problem fixing the issue with the key.